# Magento 2 - Unable to resolve the source file for image

Tags: magento2, image, static-content, static-content-deploy

I have created an image and have uploaded this to my theme/web/images folder. I have then ran the following:

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

However I cannot get the image to show on the frontend, viewing the image URL I receive the following error?

```
Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/theme/theme/en_GB/images/Delete-16.png'
#0 /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/StaticResource.php(121): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/httpdocs/pub/static.php(13): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource))
#3 {main}
```

Any ideas on how I can get my images to show?

Thanks

Comment: any solution ??

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Comment: i'm facing the same issue, but with js file, not image, have anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: @fudu have you found any solution for this? I am facing the same.

Comment: @BalwantSingh sorry, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I noticed that some image URIs were still getting wrong addresses.

I already tried clearing the cache, removing the old content manually using:

1) rm -rf var/cache/* pub/static/frontend

2) php bin/magento cache:clean

3) php bin/magento index:reindex

The above didn't resolve the issue, I also tried to re-deploy the static content for all stores.

However, bizzarely I managed to resolve it (well, it resolved itself really) by editing a _....less file from my custom theme, adding any CSS content, save, and then doing the above 3 steps resolved the issue.

I hope this helps.

Regards
Heider